# Is there any advantage in using a "repository factory" with ASP.NET MVC4 and Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am developing an application and I started to use as my base some code from an example by John Papa. Looking on the web I found this same code and it appears in an answer to a question on 
Stackoverflow.  Here is the question:

[How to de-attach an entity from a Context in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814254/how-to-de-attach-an-entity-from-a-context-in-entity-framework)

It's in the answer that was given by: SynerCoder

One part of the answer suggests the following class that is used to provide a repository from a dictionary of cached repositories. Can someone help me out and tell me is there really 
an advantage in doing this. I understand the code but can't see the point of keeping repositories in a dictionary. Would it not be the case that every new web request would see an 
empty dictionary and have to get / make a new repository anyway.

```
Data/Helpers/IRepositoryProvider.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Data.Contracts;

namespace Data.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A maker of Repositories.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// An instance of this class contains repository factory functions for different types.
    /// Each factory function takes an EF <see cref="DbContext"/> and returns
    /// a repository bound to that DbContext.
    /// <para>
    /// Designed to be a "Singleton", configured at web application start with
    /// all of the factory functions needed to create any type of repository.
    /// Should be thread-safe to use because it is configured at app start,
    /// before any request for a factory, and should be immutable thereafter.
    /// </para>
    /// </remarks>
    public class RepositoryFactories
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Return the runtime repository factory functions,
        /// each one is a factory for a repository of a particular type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// MODIFY THIS METHOD TO ADD CUSTOM FACTORY FUNCTIONS
        /// </remarks>
        private IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> GetFactories()
        {
            return new Dictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>>
                {
                   //If you have an custom implementation of an IRepository<T>
                   //{typeof(IArticleRepository), dbContext => new ArticleRepository(dbContext)}
                };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that initializes with runtime repository factories
        /// </summary>
        public RepositoryFactories()
        {
            _repositoryFactories = GetFactories();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor that initializes with an arbitrary collection of factories
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="factories">
        /// The repository factory functions for this instance. 
        /// </param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This ctor is primarily useful for testing this class
        /// </remarks>
        public RepositoryFactories(IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> factories)
        {
            _repositoryFactories = factories;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the repository factory function for the type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type serving as the repository factory lookup key.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>The repository function if found, else null.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The type parameter, T, is typically the repository type 
        /// but could be any type (e.g., an entity type)
        /// </remarks>
        public Func<DbContext, object> GetRepositoryFactory<T>()
        {

            Func<DbContext, object> factory;
            _repositoryFactories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out factory);
            return factory;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the factory for <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> where T is an entity type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The root type of the repository, typically an entity type.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>
        /// A factory that creates the <see cref="IRepository{T}"/>, given an EF <see cref="DbContext"/>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Looks first for a custom factory in <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
        /// If not, falls back to the <see cref="DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory{T}"/>.
        /// You can substitute an alternative factory for the default one by adding
        /// a repository factory for type "T" to <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
        /// </remarks>
        public Func<DbContext, object> GetRepositoryFactoryForEntityType<T>() where T : class
        {
            return GetRepositoryFactory<T>() ?? DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default factory for a <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> where T is an entity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the repository's root entity</typeparam>
        protected virtual Func<DbContext, object> DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>() where T : class
        {
            return dbContext => new EFRepository<T>(dbContext);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the dictionary of repository factory functions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// A dictionary key is a System.Type, typically a repository type.
        /// A value is a repository factory function
        /// that takes a <see cref="DbContext"/> argument and returns
        /// a repository object. Caller must know how to cast it.
        /// </remarks>
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> _repositoryFactories;
    }
}
```

Here's the code that calls the factory:

```
using System;
using Data.Contracts;
using Data.Helpers;
using Models;

namespace Data
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The "Unit of Work"
    ///     1) decouples the repos from the controllers
    ///     2) decouples the DbContext and EF from the controllers
    ///     3) manages the UoW
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This class implements the "Unit of Work" pattern in which
    /// the "UoW" serves as a facade for querying and saving to the database.
    /// Querying is delegated to "repositories".
    /// Each repository serves as a container dedicated to a particular
    /// root entity type such as a <see cref="Url"/>.
    /// A repository typically exposes "Get" methods for querying and
    /// will offer add, update, and delete methods if those features are supported.
    /// The repositories rely on their parent UoW to provide the interface to the
    /// data layer (which is the EF DbContext in this example).
    /// </remarks>
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        public UnitOfWork(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
        {
            CreateDbContext();

            repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
            RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;       
        }

        // Repositories
        public IRepository<Event> Events { get { return GetStandardRepo<Event>(); } }
        public IRepository<Candidate> Candidates { get { return GetStandardRepo<Candidate>(); } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save pending changes to the database
        /// </summary>
        public void Commit()
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Committed");
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        protected void CreateDbContext()
        {
            DbContext = new UnicornsContext();

            // Do NOT enable proxied entities, else serialization fails
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            // Load navigation properties explicitly (avoid serialization trouble)
            DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            // Because Web API will perform validation, I don't need/want EF to do so
            DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        }

        protected IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider { get; set; }

        private IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo<T>() where T : class
        {
            return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
        }
        private T GetRepo<T>() where T : class
        {
            return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
        }

        private UnicornsContext DbContext { get; set; }

        #region IDisposable

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (DbContext != null)
                {
                    DbContext.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the factory makes things more complicated that they need be. Am I correct and should I do this a simpler way such as with something like:

```
private IRepository<xx> = new GenericRepository<xx>(dbContext);
```

One more point. In my application I am using Unity. So would it be even easier to just specify the needed repositories in the constructor and have Unity create the repositories for me.  If I did this then is there a way I could pass around the dbContext so it could be used by Unity when creating the repository? Has anyone used Unity to create repositories like this?

Comment: Is your question about a general argument behind introduction of repositories or you just wonder why they've implemented then in such particular way?

Comment: I wonder why the repositories are implemented through the use of a factory rather than just with a simple: private: IRepository<xx> = new GenericRepository<Home)(dbContext)

Comment: Isn't that obvious? Imagine a unit of work with 600 repositories and compare your version with the discussed one.

Comment: You need to look at the advantages of using a factory model. That answer can be applied to your question.

Comment: @wiktor - I am sorry but I do not understand what you are trying to say. I cannot imagine a web application where in one unit 600 different entities need changing.

Comment: You say you understand the code but then you say that the UnitOfWork calls the factory. It actually calls the RepositoryProvider and it's that class that uses the RepositoryFactories class. Does that help? And if you do understand the factory class. Can you explain it to me?! I think it would help if I could see the "configured at web application" code. Off to look on sky drive now....

Answer (score 3):

OK. Here's my best shot:

1. The point of keeping repositories in a cache is to ensure that the repository is only initiated once per request. The repository cache is in the `RepositoryProvider` class and is exposed to the `UnitOfWork` by the `GetRepositoryForEntityType` method. So the advantage is that the unit of work is not concerned with caching or creation of repositories.
2. The `RepositoryProvider` class is instantiated once per unit of work. (NB - it is desirable to create the repositories new for every request). The `RepositoryProvider` keeps the repositories in a dictionary using the type as a key. This is fine when using the generic repository base which has a `Type` parameter. But what if you have created a custom repository? In this example the creation of repositories by type is handed off to the `RepositoryFactories` class via the `MakeRepository` method. The advantage is that creating repositories is separated from caching.
3. The `RepositoryFactories` class knows when to make a custom repository because it contains a dictionary that uses Type as a key and a function as a value. The function is the constructor for a custom repository. If there's a value in the dictionary then use that constructor otherwise just use the generic base constructor.

All this means that as you add entities you do not have to modify any of these classes unless you create a custom repository. And when you do that all you have to do is add an entry to the dictionary in `RepositoryFactories`

Comment: Does this mean that all callers will always get the same instance of the repository?  How does this work?  What if two instances of the uow are created, with their own DbContext's but sharing the one singleton instance of the RepositoryFactory- does this mean you could have a uow containing repositories which potentially use a different DbContext instance, with a different change tracker etc?

Comment: No, all callers don't get the same instance of a repository. A new repository is instantiated for each request.