# Multiple dbcontexts with Repository, UnitOfWork and Ninject

Tags: entity-framework, ninject, repository-pattern, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I am slowly getting to grips with EF, repository, UnitOfWork and Ninject and have included my implementation so far (see below).

The purpose of my data layer is to provide the ability to read data from the existing HR system which has an Oracle back end, and provide addition functionality by consuming this data. The application I am building will use a SQL backend, currently I have just created some extra tables in the HR systems Oracle dbm but I want to keep this separate and hook in to features such as SQL dependency and service broker.

My data layer is completely abstracted from my application(s) and is split in to Data, Data.Contracts and Models. I have been using a code first approach for my own tables and have used Devart's dotConnect for Oracle to map the Oracle database and generate my models for me.

Finally I have a business layer where I inject the UnitOfWork and keep all my business logic, the business layer is then Injected in my presentation layer. Eventually this will be replaced by a service layer so my data can be maintained in a single place for all our systems, but I'm not quite there yet.

I would really appreciate if anyone can review my code so far and show me how I can introduce multiple dbcontexts (SQL & Oracle) which can be used seamlessly with the same UnitOfWork.

Finally I also am struggling to work out how I can have a generic repository pattern which I can assign to all models, but then also create model specific repositories or even additional generic repository methods that could be assigned to specific models. E.g. I may want to provide methods to read all models, but I may only want to have the ability to add, edit, delete on certain models.

Many thanks,

Andy

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Data.Contracts;

namespace Data.Helpers
{
/// <summary>
/// Interface for a class that can provide repositories by type.
/// The class may create the repositories dynamically if it is unable
/// to find one in its cache of repositories.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Repositories created by this provider tend to require a <see cref="DbContext"/>
/// to retrieve data.
/// </remarks>
public interface IRepositoryProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set the <see cref="DbContext"/> with which to initialize a repository
    /// if one must be created.
    /// </summary>
    DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> for entity type, T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// Root entity type of the <see cref="IRepository{T}"/>.
    /// </typeparam>
    IRepository<T> GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>() where T : class;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a repository of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// Type of the repository, typically a custom repository interface.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="factory">
    /// An optional repository creation function that takes a <see cref="DbContext"/>
    /// and returns a repository of T. Used if the repository must be created.
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Looks for the requested repository in its cache, returning if found.
    /// If not found, tries to make one with the factory, fallingback to 
    /// a default factory if the factory parameter is null.
    /// </remarks>
    T GetRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory = null) where T : class;


    /// <summary>
    /// Set the repository to return from this provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Set a repository if you don't want this provider to create one.
    /// Useful in testing and when developing without a backend
    /// implementation of the object returned by a repository of type T.
    /// </remarks>
    void SetRepository<T>(T repository);
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Data.Contracts;

namespace Data.Helpers
{
/// <summary>
/// A maker of Repositories.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// An instance of this class contains repository factory functions for different types.
/// Each factory function takes an EF <see cref="DbContext"/> and returns
/// a repository bound to that DbContext.
/// <para>
/// Designed to be a "Singleton", configured at web application start with
/// all of the factory functions needed to create any type of repository.
/// Should be thread-safe to use because it is configured at app start,
/// before any request for a factory, and should be immutable thereafter.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
public class RepositoryFactories
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the runtime repository factory functions,
    /// each one is a factory for a repository of a particular type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// MODIFY THIS METHOD TO ADD CUSTOM FACTORY FUNCTIONS
    /// </remarks>
    private IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> GetFactories()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>>
            {
               //{typeof(IArticleRepository), dbContext => new ArticleRepository(dbContext)},
               //{typeof(IUrlRepository), dbContext => new UrlRepository(dbContext)},
            };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that initializes with runtime repository factories
    /// </summary>
    public RepositoryFactories()
    {
        _repositoryFactories = GetFactories();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that initializes with an arbitrary collection of factories
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="factories">
    /// The repository factory functions for this instance. 
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This ctor is primarily useful for testing this class
    /// </remarks>
    public RepositoryFactories(IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> factories)
    {
        _repositoryFactories = factories;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the repository factory function for the type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type serving as the repository factory lookup key.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The repository function if found, else null.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The type parameter, T, is typically the repository type 
    /// but could be any type (e.g., an entity type)
    /// </remarks>
    public Func<DbContext, object> GetRepositoryFactory<T>()
    {

        Func<DbContext, object> factory;
        _repositoryFactories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out factory);
        return factory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the factory for <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> where T is an entity type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The root type of the repository, typically an entity type.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>
    /// A factory that creates the <see cref="IRepository{T}"/>, given an EF <see cref="DbContext"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Looks first for a custom factory in <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
    /// If not, falls back to the <see cref="DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory{T}"/>.
    /// You can substitute an alternative factory for the default one by adding
    /// a repository factory for type "T" to <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    public Func<DbContext, object> GetRepositoryFactoryForEntityType<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetRepositoryFactory<T>() ?? DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default factory for a <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> where T is an entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the repository's root entity</typeparam>
    protected virtual Func<DbContext, object> DefaultEntityRepositoryFactory<T>() where T : class
    {
        return dbContext => new EFRepository<T>(dbContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the dictionary of repository factory functions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// A dictionary key is a System.Type, typically a repository type.
    /// A value is a repository factory function
    /// that takes a <see cref="DbContext"/> argument and returns
    /// a repository object. Caller must know how to cast it.
    /// </remarks>
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> _repositoryFactories;
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Data.Contracts;

namespace Data.Helpers
{
/// <summary>
/// Provides an <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> for a client request.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Caches repositories of a given type so that repositories are only created once per provider.
/// create a new provider per client request.
/// </remarks>
public class RepositoryProvider : IRepositoryProvider
{
    public RepositoryProvider(RepositoryFactories repositoryFactories)
    {
        _repositoryFactories = repositoryFactories;
        Repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and set the <see cref="DbContext"/> with which to initialize a repository
    /// if one must be created.
    /// </summary>
    public DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or create-and-cache the default <see cref="IRepository{T}"/> for an entity of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// Root entity type of the <see cref="IRepository{T}"/>.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If can't find repository in cache, use a factory to create one.
    /// </remarks>
    public IRepository<T> GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetRepository<IRepository<T>>(
            _repositoryFactories.GetRepositoryFactoryForEntityType<T>());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or create-and-cache a repository of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// Type of the repository, typically a custom repository interface.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="factory">
    /// An optional repository creation function that takes a DbContext argument
    /// and returns a repository of T. Used if the repository must be created and
    /// caller wants to specify the specific factory to use rather than one
    /// of the injected <see cref="RepositoryFactories"/>.
    /// </param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Looks for the requested repository in its cache, returning if found.
    /// If not found, tries to make one using <see cref="MakeRepository{T}"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    public virtual T GetRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory = null) where T : class
    {
        // Look for T dictionary cache under typeof(T).
        object repoObj;
        Repositories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out repoObj);
        if (repoObj != null)
        {
            return (T)repoObj;
        }

        // Not found or null; make one, add to dictionary cache, and return it.
        return MakeRepository<T>(factory, DbContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the dictionary of repository objects, keyed by repository type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Caller must know how to cast the repository object to a useful type.
    /// <p>This is an extension point. You can register fully made repositories here
    /// and they will be used instead of the ones this provider would otherwise create.</p>
    /// </remarks>
    protected Dictionary<Type, object> Repositories { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>Make a repository of type T.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of repository to make.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="dbContext">
    /// The <see cref="DbContext"/> with which to initialize the repository.
    /// </param>        
    /// <param name="factory">
    /// Factory with <see cref="DbContext"/> argument. Used to make the repository.
    /// If null, gets factory from <see cref="_repositoryFactories"/>.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual T MakeRepository<T>(Func<DbContext, object> factory, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        var f = factory ?? _repositoryFactories.GetRepositoryFactory<T>();
        if (f == null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("No factory for repository type, " + typeof(T).FullName);
        }
        var repo = (T)f(dbContext);
        Repositories[typeof(T)] = repo;
        return repo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the repository for type T that this provider should return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Plug in a custom repository if you don't want this provider to create one.
    /// Useful in testing and when developing without a backend
    /// implementation of the object returned by a repository of type T.
    /// </remarks>
    public void SetRepository<T>(T repository)
    {
        Repositories[typeof(T)] = repository;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="RepositoryFactories"/> with which to create a new repository.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Should be initialized by constructor injection
    /// </remarks>
    private RepositoryFactories _repositoryFactories;
    }
}

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using Data.Contracts;

namespace Data
{
/// <summary>
/// The EF-dependent, generic repository for data access
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of entity for this Repository.</typeparam>
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        //return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(PredicateBuilder.GetByIdPredicate<T>(id));
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        if (entity == null) return; // not found; assume already deleted.
        Delete(entity);
    }
    }
}

using System;
using Data.Contracts;
using Data.Helpers;
using Models;

namespace Data
{
/// <summary>
/// The "Unit of Work"
///     1) decouples the repos from the controllers
///     2) decouples the DbContext and EF from the controllers
///     3) manages the UoW
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class implements the "Unit of Work" pattern in which
/// the "UoW" serves as a facade for querying and saving to the database.
/// Querying is delegated to "repositories".
/// Each repository serves as a container dedicated to a particular
/// root entity type such as a <see cref="Url"/>.
/// A repository typically exposes "Get" methods for querying and
/// will offer add, update, and delete methods if those features are supported.
/// The repositories rely on their parent UoW to provide the interface to the
/// data layer (which is the EF DbContext in this example).
/// </remarks>
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public UnitOfWork(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        CreateDbContext();

        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
    }

    // repositories
    public IRepository<DASH_PYLVR> DASH_PYLVRs { get { return GetStandardRepo<DASH_PYLVR>(); } }
    public IRepository<DASH_SickRecord> DASH_SickRecords { get { return GetStandardRepo<DASH_SickRecord>(); } }
    public IRepository<EMDET> EMDETs { get { return GetStandardRepo<EMDET>(); } }
    public IRepository<EMLVA> EMLVAs { get { return GetStandardRepo<EMLVA>(); } }
    public IRepository<EMLVE> EMLVEs { get { return GetStandardRepo<EMLVE>(); } }
    public IRepository<EMMPO> EMMPOs { get { return GetStandardRepo<EMMPO>(); } }
    public IRepository<EMPOS> EMPOSs { get { return GetStandardRepo<EMPOS>(); } }
    public IRepository<EVENTLOG> EVENTLOGs { get { return GetStandardRepo<EVENTLOG>(); } }
    public IRepository<IDMSTAGING> IDMSTAGINGs { get { return GetStandardRepo<IDMSTAGING>(); } }
    public IRepository<PP_BRADFORD> PP_BRADFORDs { get { return GetStandardRepo<PP_BRADFORD>(); } }
    public IRepository<PP_BRADFORD_SCORES> PP_BRADFORD_SCORESs { get { return GetStandardRepo<PP_BRADFORD_SCORES>(); } }
    public IRepository<PSDET> PSDETs { get { return GetStandardRepo<PSDET>(); } }
    public IRepository<PSLDW> PSLDWs { get { return GetStandardRepo<PSLDW>(); } }
    public IRepository<UPZ88> UPZ88s { get { return GetStandardRepo<UPZ88>(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save pending changes to the database
    /// </summary>
    public void Commit()
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Committed");
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected void CreateDbContext()
    {
        DbContext = new CHRISCSEntities();

        // Do NOT enable proxied entities, else serialization fails
        DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        // Load navigation properties explicitly (avoid serialization trouble)
        DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        // Because Web API will perform validation, I don't need/want EF to do so
        DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    protected IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider { get; set; }

    private IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
    }
    private T GetRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
    }

    private CHRISCSEntities DbContext { get; set; }

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (DbContext != null)
            {
                DbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
    }
}


using System.Linq;

namespace Data.Contracts
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(int id);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Delete(int id);
    }
}

using Models;

namespace Data.Contracts
{
/// <summary>
/// Interface for the "Unit of Work"
/// </summary>
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    // Save pending changes to the data store.
    void Commit();

    // Repositories
    IRepository<DASH_PYLVR> DASH_PYLVRs { get; }
    IRepository<DASH_SickRecord> DASH_SickRecords { get; }
    IRepository<EMDET> EMDETs { get; }
    IRepository<EMLVA> EMLVAs { get; }
    IRepository<EMLVE> EMLVEs { get; }
    IRepository<EMMPO> EMMPOs { get; }
    IRepository<EMPOS> EMPOSs { get; }
    IRepository<EVENTLOG> EVENTLOGs { get; }
    IRepository<IDMSTAGING> IDMSTAGINGs { get; }
    IRepository<PP_BRADFORD> PP_BRADFORDs { get; }
    IRepository<PP_BRADFORD_SCORES> PP_BRADFORD_SCORESs { get; }
    IRepository<PSDET> PSDETs { get; }
    IRepository<PSLDW> PSLDWs { get; }
    IRepository<UPZ88> UPZ88s { get; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like John Papa's code. I attempted a [basic explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212706/150342) of it before.

Lets say you want to make your `ArticleRepository` read only. Then you could do this:

```
public class ArticleRepository: EFRepository<Article>
{
   //Add a custom implementation - you can add custom methods here but this one is empty 
   //because we are hiding functions rather than creating new functions
   //We inherit from EFRepository so this class has Insert and Update methods, 
   //but that doesn't matter because we only expose the FindById and GetAll methods 
   //in the interface
}

public interface IArticleRepository
{
   //A custom interface that only exposes what you want
   FindById(int id);
   GetAll();
}
```

As for multiple contexts, I have no experience with it so I am probably under-qualified, but I think you should be able to add your second context to your unit of work in the same way as the first and then if there are saves going on that span more than 1 context, then do it using `TransactionScope()`

Now - this is the place in your code that you should specify how to create custom repositories:

```
/// MODIFY THIS METHOD TO ADD CUSTOM FACTORY FUNCTIONS
/// </remarks>
private IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> GetFactories()
{
    return new Dictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>>
        {
           //{typeof(IArticleRepository), dbContext => new ArticleRepository(dbContext)},
           //{typeof(IUrlRepository), dbContext => new UrlRepository(dbContext)},
        };
}
```

Just un-comment the first entry in the `Dictionary` and the `RepositoryProvider` will return an instance of the `ArticleRepository` class when you ask for an `IArticleRepository` in your unit of work

In this particular example (where the implementation is empty) you don't even need the `ArticleRepository` class. You could use this line for the `Dictionary` entry instead:

`{typeof(IArticleRepository), dbContext => new EFRepository<Article>(dbContext)}`

Other references:

[The repository and unit of work patterns](http://www.tigranetworks.co.uk/blogs/electricdreams/grokking-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns/)

[John Papa's original source](https://github.com/johnpapa/CodeCamper)

[How to ensure proxies are created when using the repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736143/how-to-ensure-proxies-are-created-when-using-the-repository-pattern-with-entity?lq=1)

Comment: is there any way to make IRepositoryProvider/RepositoryFactory generic to support multiple dbcontext. Right now its CreateDbContext() wich is hard coded to instatiate "One" dbcontext. Is this possible? thanks!

Comment: The `CreateDbContext` method in this example is in the implementation of the `IUnitOfWork`. You should be able to create as many `DbContexts` in that method as you wish. Or you could chose to inject the context via the unit of work's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a go with your recommendation of editing the unitofwork...

I have a few questions and I think this is the code that will be affected:

```
protected void CreateDbContext()
    {
        DbContext = new CHRISCSEntities();

        // Do NOT enable proxied entities, else serialization fails
        DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        // Load navigation properties explicitly (avoid serialization trouble)
        DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        // Because Web API will perform validation, I don't need/want EF to do so
        DbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    protected IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider { get; set; }

    private IRepository<T> GetStandardRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryForEntityType<T>();
    }
    private T GetRepo<T>() where T : class
    {
        return RepositoryProvider.GetRepository<T>();
    }

    private CHRISCSEntities DbContext { get; set; }
```

So this is creating the reference to DbContext, and is currently strongly typed to "CHRISCSEntities"

I guess I need to inject? the dbcontext at this point so I can set it to the DbContext I am interested in right?

I will give a personal disclaimer, I am still a relative newb with all things DAL so please forgive any stupid questions :)

I'm not entirely sure where I should do this or whether I need to make some kind of DbContext Factory?

Can we use ninject to inject the correct DbContext for a specific entity and keep track of the injected DbContext?

Comment: I've had a play with this: http://www.cnblogs.com/Seekr/archive/2012/08/29/2661632.html  but I can't seem to work out how this works with my RepositoryProvider and RepositoryFactories and my UnitOfWork? Currently in my UnitOfWork I define all my repositories like this: public IRepository<EMLVE> EMLVEs { get { return GetStandardRepo<EMLVE>(); } } But I would guess this should be changed too?