# Call multiple service method in one transaction

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, transactionscope

Forgive me I am not good at EF6. If I make some mistake . Please help me to correct it. Thanks.

Firstly I want to implement the business logic in my service layer like below.

```
public class userService
{
    void createWithCommit(User user)
    {
        MyEntityContext db= new MyEntityContext ();
        ...
        db.Users.add(user);//Add a new user entity
        ....
        Work w = new Work();
        ... 
        db.Works.add(w);//Add a new work entity
        db.savechanges();//commit the changes which will insert 2 new record . one is user . another is work.
    }
}
```

But in some service class I want to call multiple others service method in one transaction like below.

```
class utilService
{
    void update(SomeClass cls)
    {
        using (var tran=new TransactionScope())
        {
          userService userSvr= new userService();
          userSvr.create();//this method already include a savechanges().
          jobService jobSvr= new jobService();
          jobSvr.update();//this method may include another savechanges().
          tran.Complete();//I don't why EF6 doesn't have the Commit method. just has the Complete method.
        }

    }
}
```

So I can use it in the ASP.net MVC controller like below.

```
class SomeController
{
    ActionResult index()
    {
        userService userSvr = new userService();
        userSvr.createWithCommit();

    }

    ActionResult util()
    {
        utilService utilSvr = new utilService ();
        userSvr.update(....);

    }
}
```

So you can see my idea is I want to include multiple service method into one transaction. and each of the included service methods may or may not include the code `SaveChanges()` (That means a transaction is committed. Right ?).

And you can see . In my test , I tried to use the `TransactionScope` to include multiple service method into one transaction. I mean it in the method `utilService.update()`. But It seems the `TransactionScope` not work after the  `SaveChanges() is called`. So My question is :

Is there any possibility to implement it as my idea ? If there is . What kind of pattern should I apply ? (I heard of UOW and Repository pattern . Are they the solution? Thanks.)

Comment: a unit of work pattern will solve your problem,

Comment: This might help you to implement UOW http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548531/unit-of-work-repository-pattern-the-fall-of-the-business-transaction-concept

Comment: Thanks Eldho, Could you please share some sample or read to me . So I can better understand it ? I really don't know how to get start with it . Thanks.

Comment: http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to implement Unit of work pattern to avoid transaction scope.`Unit of Work` and `Repository Pattern` is something used fairly widely nowadays.
>
> UoW exposes public method `Commit` to store the changes.

**Generic Repository**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal SchoolContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

**UnitOFWork**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    //Context Creation in the UnitOfWork
    //This context is supplied to all Repository 
    //Hence One Commit save All Changes
    private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
    private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
    private GenericRepository<Course> courseRepository;

    public GenericRepository<Department> DepartmentRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.departmentRepository == null)
            {
                this.departmentRepository = new GenericRepository<Department>(context);
            }
            return departmentRepository;
        }
    }

    public GenericRepository<Course> CourseRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.courseRepository == null)
            {
                this.courseRepository = new GenericRepository<Course>(context);
            }
            return courseRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
  //Sample Controller
 public class CourseController : Controller
   {
      //Initialize the unit of work here
      private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

      Public Void MyBussinessTransaction()
      {
         unitOfWork.CourseRepository.Insert(course);
         unitOfWork.DepartmentRepository.Insert(department)
         unitOfWork.Save();
      }
   }
```

[Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[Martin Flower explanation of UOW](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)

Comment: Thanks, Very nice . But What is the `GenericRepository`? Could you please post some code here .Thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang please see the updated answer, you could find more detail of this [here] (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: In your UOW pattern . I found we have to commit transaction in the UI presentation layer. because controller belong to the UI layer.So I wondered If we can do that in the UI layer. I mean call unitOfWork.save() in the controller.

Comment: @Joe.wang This is based on basic implementation in msdn, Generally this `save()` will be at the data layer and through data transfer objects we transfer data from data to business

Comment: yeah , I also found it in the msdn site. +1