# Where is IDbSet<T> in entity core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

[image]

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private ShopCoreDbContext dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet; //here
    protected IDbFactory DbFactory { get; private set; }
    protected ShopCoreDbContext DbContext
    {
        get => dbContext ?? (dbContext = DbFactory.Init());
    }
    protected RepositoryBase(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        DbFactory = dbFactory;
        dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }
    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        return dbSet.Add(entity); //err here
    } 
}
```

With IDbSet nothing happen. But IDbSet interface no longer exists in entity core. This is error detail:

> cannot implicitly convert type  Microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry to T

It requires it must be an interface.
So what should I do now?

Comment: Please include code as text in a `code` section and **not** as image.

Comment: i dont now how to add a beautiful block of code so i think the picture of it is better

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31944364/1876572

Comment: yeah, it works when I change return type to void, but why it not works, this is a code I get frome github, I dont know why, is there any change from entity framework. but i see it also have return type, by the way, what is it?
public virtual EntityEntry<TEntity> Add([NotNullAttribute] TEntity entity);

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem:

The `Add` method doesn't return the entity directly, but a wrapper entity. Use its `.Entity` property to get back the value (or return the passed in value):

```
    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        return dbSet.Add(entity).Entity; 
    }
```

About the `IDbSet<T>` interface: Entity Framework Core does not have an `IDbSet<T>` interface.

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1282) there is no plan to bring it back since `DbSet<T>` is now an abstract base class that can be used to mock for testing or subclassed:

> The issue with interfaces is we either exclude new members or break folks who implement the interface. The base class is also slightly better for folks writing their own test doubles (rather than using a mocking framework) since you only need to implement the methods you actually use.
>
> […]
>
> Closing as we have been using the base type approach in EF6.x for a few releases now and have not heard any feedback on real scenarios where this doesn't work as well.